# Update Full Name in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

I've been thrust into the deep end with Active Directory (I'm a web developer, go fig) I have a user that I've changed first/last name on but the Full Name hasn't changed which is causing issues with sharing off a BCM database. How do I refresh it so the Full Name is updated.

I have no idea how AD works but for some reason the higher ups have decided it's my job.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on .NET 3.5 ? If so, go check out this MSDN article: [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx).

Check out this CodeProject article: [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)

Check out this [list of Code Samples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) for System.DirectoryServices on MSDN.

If you're serious about Active Directory Programming in C# or VB.NET, go buy this book:

[The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170)

[image]

Updating the "full name" (really: DisplayName) should be as easy as (on .NET 3.5):

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourDomain");

UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "(your user name)");

if (up != null)  // we found the user
{
   up.DisplayName = "new display name for your user";
   up.Save();
}
```

That's it! :-)

Mind you : you need to pass in the NetBIOS domain name (e.g. "MICROSOFT") - not a DNS-style name (microsoft.com) to the constructor of the PrincipalContext.

Hope this helps!

Marc

**UPDATE for .NET 2.0:**

Here's the code if you're running on .NET 2.0 and need to update the "displayName" for a user, given his "SAMAccountName" (his username without the domain, basically):

```
// set the root for the search
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=yourcompany,dc=com");

// searcher to find user in question
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(root);

// set options
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectCategory=Person))", yourUserName);

// do we find anyone by that name??
SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();

if (result != null)
{
    // if yes - retrieve the full DirectoryEntry for that user
    DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

    // set the "displayName" property to the new value
    userEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value = yourNewUserFullName;

    // save changes back to AD store
    userEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted it but not tried it, .net 3.5 isn't installed and I've been told not to run any code or do anything with it. So basically I have a problem that I've been told to fix and then told I can't fix.

Again thanks for your help.

Comment: what version of .NET are you running? 2.0 ? I'll update my post with a sample for the 2.0 version, too - it's just a bit more involved than the nice 3.5 version....